# How to add Unity 3d's unity View in iOS app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine, subview

I want to add `Unity3d` project's `UnityView` in my application.

I had succesfully imported project from Unity 3d & add code from it into my application.

Project builded succesfully. But as we knew there will only one `main.m` file in project. But below function in `UnityAppController.h` make difficulty for me.

```
inline UnityAppController*  GetAppController()
{
    return (UnityAppController*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
}
```

Whenever i call method on `UnityAppController` its applied on `Appdelegate` class,
so i get crash like `unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

If any of you have any guidance for me regarding this then please help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to :- https://github.com/frederik-jacques/native-ios-and-unity3d

and import `TNAppController.mm` class.

Replace `createViewHierarchyImpl` with

```
 -(void)willStartWithViewController:(UIViewController*)controller
```

Add this line to addView :

```
[self.view addSubview:GetAppController().unityView];
```

If you still facing issue then let me know.

Comment: Works this solution like a charm

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I'm using `AppDelegate` as my `AppControllerClassName` in my `main.mm` file. I do face the same error as above where `AppDelegate` is returned however it's a `UnityAppController` object. I've tried overriding the method in `UnityAppController.h` `#import "AppDelegate.h"
inline UnityAppController *GetAppController() {
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    return delegate.unityController;
}` but I get an error of `AppDelegate` unknown type ... any suggestions is appreciated!